# Achievements wrong messages

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, privileges

Some days ago [this](http://s12.postimg.org/4tsv9hyot/bug.jpg) happened to me... as you can see I have only 6 reputation and those are not supposed to appear now. Anyone checking my reputation can see that it did not change above 6 in ages (weeks, actually).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28354287) was [briefly accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28353993/timeline) and gave you an additional 15 reputation for a whole four seconds, which was apparently enough time for the system to send you the messages about the privileges you gained (since you were sitting at 21 reputation at the time).

Comment: But why this +15/-15 not shown in user's reputation history ?

Comment: Oh. Thank you. How can I access those additional information of questions and profiles?

Comment: @Krishnabhadra Reversals that occur on the same day as the original event get collapsed and hidden in the reputation history.

Comment: @krishnabhadra thats why I wondered about those messages, I didnt see my reputation history change.

Comment: Thank you animuson. Maybe history events that fires a message should not be hidden.

Comment: @animuson Hmm, why is that? What is the purpose of hiding these messages?

Comment: @Krishnabhadra Because otherwise [people start doing this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124738/new-reputation-is-too-verbose-upvote-unupvote-upvote-again).

Comment: By the way, if its intentional it means its not a bug, so I will remove the bug tag.
Edit: I can't remove the bug tag, lol... so let it be.

Comment: @animuson haha, fair point. Thanks for the link. Upvoted